# PHPStorm hangs on highlighting a word, then Ctrl+Shift+F

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I have PHPStorm 2.1.5. It could be that you encountered this, if so please suggest.

Generally, I don't care when and how ofter PHPStorm hangs, but this one is very consistent and annoying, because I cannot search a string.

Thanks.

Comment: P.S. It looks like when not highlighting a word, the popup appears. So this could be a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

It had a very deep symlinked directory. Adding it to excludes, solves this problem.

Comment: What do you mean adding to to excludes?  Where is this excludes you speak of?

Comment: There's Directories options in the Settings (also the button for Settings exists on the panel). Just select there all dirs, then R-click and Exclude.